# Validation for Integer value

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, plsql

I want to validate one column `AMOUNT Varchar(2)` which should contains only integer value.
I am using below logic :

```
 IF regexp_like(amount,'^[0-9]+') THEN
        X_STATUS:=true;
           else X_STATUS:=false;
            X_REMARKS:='amount SHOULD BE INTEGER';
            RETURN;
        END IF;
```

But it doesn't work , Kindly help me for the optimal solution:
Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? Is there an error message? Do you get un-expected results? does the code invalidate legitimate digits or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your code:

```
regexp_like(amount,'^[0-9]+')
```

It checks if `amount` *starts* with a digit - but other characters may be anything. Typically, it would allow something like `'1A'`, `'2$'` or `3%'`.

Consider:

```
regexp_like(amount,'^[0-9]+$')
```

`$` represents the end of the string in the regex, so this means: all characters must be digits.

If you want to allow the empty string as well (which the above expression does not do), you can change quantifier `+` to `*`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an anchor for the end of the string:

```
IF regexp_like(amount, '^[0-9]+$')
```

This matches *all* characters in the string.

If you don't want leading zeros either, then:

```
IF regexp_like(amount, '^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$')
```

And this assumes that you don't want negative numbers.  If you do:

```
IF regexp_like(amount, '^(-?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$')
```